# How to route to a page on click event in apex charts?

Tags: reactjs, charts, apex, apexcharts

A beginner in react... I am able to reach a function post-click event of a bar but unable to route to a link or page.
I may have other defined routes to which I want to go, like a page consisting of a table, listing all the sales and it automatically gets filtered. How am I supposed to do that? Please guide me through. I have searched for this a lot and finally was able to reach a function but now I am stuck.

```
class SalesWidget2 extends Component {
  
  routeChange(index){
    console.log('I am here');
    // let history = useHistory();
    // history.push('google.com');
  }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
          this.state = {
            colors:['#FEB019'], 
            series: [{
              name: 'Sales  ',
              type: 'column',
              data: [1.4, 2, 2.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.8, 3.8, 4.6],
              
            }],
            options: {
              chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                height: 350,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif',
                fontSize: '14px',
                events:{
                  click: (event, chartContext, config) =>{
                    this.routeChange(config.dataPointIndex);
                  }
                },
              },
              plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                  borderRadius: 4,
                  horizontal: false,
                }
              },
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              },
              title: {
                text: 'My Store Performance',
                align: 'left',
                offsetX: 50,
                fontSize: '14px',
              },
              xaxis: {
                title: {
                  text: 'Time',
                  style: {
                    fontSize: '14px',
                  },
                },
                categories: ['June 2021', 'July 2021','August 2021', 'September 2021', 'October 2021','November 2021','December 2021', 'January 2022'],
                
              },
              yaxis:{
                title: {
                  text: 'Sales',
                  style: {
                    fontSize: '14px',
                  }
                },
                labels:{                  
                  formatter: function(val) {
                    return  val.toFixed(1);
                  }
                }
              },
              tooltip: {
                x:{
                  title:{
                    text: 'Sales',
                  }
                },
                y: {
                  formatter: function(val) {
                    return "&dollar;" + val.toFixed(0) + " million";
                  }
                }
              },
              fill:{
                colors:['#FEB019'],
              },
              stroke:{
                colors:['#FEB019'],
              },
              legend: {
                horizontalAlign: 'left',
                offsetX: 40,
                fontSize: '14px',
              },
              responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 1000,
                options: {
                  plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                      horizontal:true,
                      vertical: false,
                    }
                  },
                  legend:{
                    position: "bottom"
                  },
                  yaxis:{
                    labels:{
                      formatter: function(val) {
                        return  val.toFixed(0);
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  xaxis:{
                    labels:{
                      formatter: function(val) {
                        return  val.toFixed(1);
                      }
                    }
                  },

                },
                
                
                
              }],

            },
            
          
          
          
          
          };
    }
    render() {
      return(
      
        <Chart options={this.state.options} series={this.state.series} type="bar" height="350" />
      )
    
    }}
```